# Node lambda not writing to DynamoDB and no error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

```
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'})
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'})
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
  const params = {
    TableName: 'TC_QUESTIONS',
    Item: {
      'questionId' : {S: '001'},
      'questionText' : {S: 'Richard Roe'}
    }
  }

  var putItemPromise = docClient.put(params).promise()
  putItemPromise.then(function(data) {
    console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  });

  await putItemPromise
```

No error is returned. No success callback. When I use the wrong column name I get an error back from Dynamo. I've tried running the it locally and on lambda. It executes, and exits. No rows get added to the Table. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Here is my CF for the DynamoDB table:

```
QuestionsTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: 'TC_QUESTIONS'
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: questionId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: questionText
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: questionId
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: questionText
        KeyType: RANGE
    ProvisionedThroughput: 
      ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
      WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-1'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const params = {
      TableName: 'TC_QUESTIONS',
      Item: {
        'questionId': '001',
        'questionText' : 'Richard Roe'
      }
    }
  
    try {
      await docClient.put(params).promise()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
};
```

If your table exists and questionId is your partition key, the code above works.

I think you were mixing things up a little bit, because since you're using [DocClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) you don't need to specify DynamoDB's types. This was the problem on your code. Just specify the raw values (like I did above, passing the String itself) and it will work.

Comment: OK thanks, I removed the types, but am getting the same result. I added the Cloudformation for the Table. Am I missing something about the partition key?

Comment: I confirmed in the console that questionId is the partition key. Really stumped here, still not getting anything added to the table. Confirmed by looking at the console.

Comment: OK.. I had my code in a module that was being imported and called from the lambda handler. Moving this dynamo code directly into the handler, and everything works... Something about the way I'm organising the files/modules is wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: And probably you were not getting any results because the code I created as a sample is `async` so it returns a promise. On your client's code , you should also `await` on it, then it should work without having to move the code inside your handler.

Comment: In case you want to know more about async/await: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: That was indeed it - I was missing an await. Thanks again :)